# canvas not found in game view with unity

Tags: unity, gearvr

I am working on a GearVR app with Unity3D.I have an environement and I have placed a canvas in the scene.I have set the canvas Render mode to "**World Space**".But when I runned my project,the canvas is getting displayed on the scene view,but in the game view the canvas is not getting on the scene.But whereas in the camera view its showing the canvas.What will be the issue?.

When I set me canvas Rendere mode to **Screen Space-Overlay** the canvas is getting displayed in the scene but as the lookup change,the canvas is also moving along with the camera

Can anybody please help me out.

Comment: When set to Screen space "World space", you will have to correctly set the size and the position of the canvas. I guess the latter is too big. The default size is the size of your game view. You will have to set the size to something like 2 x 1 units only.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got solved.I was unity 5.3.4 for developing the gearvr application.I switched the unity version to 5.4.2.Now the canvas is displayed on the screen.I searched a lot on this.It stated that there is problem with canvas rendereing in 5.3 on wards.